# How to save OpenGL textures when lose context on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, message, egl, openglcontext

Our game requires that several large textures are built up dynamically from small images, and we don't keep a data copy of the textures, we just use OpenGL with `glTexSubImage2d` to update the actual textures.

When Back is pressed, or the game loses focus, we want to save these textures to ram, so if the user then goes back to the game, we can recreate/reload them in `onSurfaceCreated`. We already reload from 'disk' all static textures.

However, its proving hard to find out where we can get a message to know that we are about to lose the EGL context. If we set a flag in the main activity's `onBackPressed` then check that flag in the main render loop, we can save the textures there, but we can't access the textures from the main activity, so putting the call in the main activity's `onStop` callback is too late. There is no subsequent render loop to save the textures, as, well, its stopped by then. We need to do this as there will be other ways where `onStop` is called other than pressing the Back button.

Supposedly I can't delay `onStop` to get one more "render" in either. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried binding the textures to a FBO and then call glReadPixels to copy the texture data to memory?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I get the data from the textures, but the problem is knowing when to do this - I need to do it in the render thread just before I lose the EGL context.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already generate this textures dynamically during the cold start of your application, it may be a good point just to part this textures `dirty` and regenerate them just as if your application was starting cold.

If you want to save those textures then don't wait for `onStop()` to be called. Just save them once you have generated their content.

Comment: They constantly get updated with new graphics as new animations are loaded, also "saving" them takes up extra memory - the plan is to copy the data to a memory buffer and free the gl texture, thus getting back the memory you've just allocated. Then reverse when you re-upload them. We could do this periodically, but it takes time and would always be a bit out of date.

Comment: @user3162134: why don't you want marking them as ``dirty`` in the first place?

Comment: I can rebuild most of these textures by reloading in the small segments, but some other parts are very hard to recreate, e.g. snapshots made from lots of small parts, and this does take quite a while - 10 seconds plus - hence why I want to save the complete texture state

Comment: @user3162134: can you split this task and do it iteratively during a number of frames?

Comment: If we rebuild these textures on reload it needs to be done before we can render things as these textures hold all the objects in our game world. Other textures load in very quickly, these take longer as they have to be "put together"

Comment: @user3162134: You will have to choose either way: save frequently or rebuild.

Comment: So it seems... Saving them once when I get onBackPressed works for that situation, as there seems to be another render before the EGL context is destroyed, but if another app forces its way to the front, e.g. a phone call, and the EGL context is lost then, then I have no time to save them. I'll will let you know if I find a way..

Comment: @user3162134: but there is no warranty that there always will be another render after ``onStop``. Sounds like a hack to me.

Comment: There is very rarely another render after onStop, that's why I'm doing it on onBackPressed, which seems to work on every device we've tried so far.

Comment: @user3162134: Indeed, ``onBackPressed`` allows you to postpone the exit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as a problem of synchronising threads. The button pressed event or the onPause event (in case another app goes to the front) runs on the main (UI) thread, while the opengl render has his own thread. When the events on UI thread are triggered, you set a flag and wait on a condition_variable. the render thread checks always the flag, and when it is set then saves the textures, changes the condition of the condition_variable and notifies the UI thread.